# Как сортировать массив структур через указатели?

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Начал изучать структуры, и выпала задача, где нужно сортировать структуру по определенному полю. Использовал обычную сортировку, но она оказывается нерациональна. Можете кто-нибудь привести пример сортировки структуры через указатели? Как это вообще делается? Допустим, дана структура со студентами и ее надо отсортировать по количеству баллов за тест. Как это сделать наиболее рационально, если просто сортировка по полю считается нерациональной. Надо использовать указатели, но как это организовать?

```
struct Students
{
    string name;
    string surname;
    int test1;
};
Students student[100];
```

Comment: указатель ссылается на какой нибудь элемент в структуре. вопрос мне не понятен.вы хотите сортировать структуру по особому полю в структуре? приложите структуру в вопрос, пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Senoit Auomator, добавил структуру

Comment: У вас какая-то непонятная смесь понятий. Понятие поля и понятие указателя - совершенно разные вещи...

Comment: @IWProgrammer  Вопрос совершенно не понятен. С одной стороны, надо сортировать структуру по полю, с другой стороны, это совершенно не рационально. Так что надо сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef struct {
  std::string name;
  std::string surname;
  int test;
} StudentsType;

int main () {
  StudentsType student[3] = {
    {name: "Иван", surname: "Иванов", test: 3},
    {name: "Петр", surname: "Петров", test: 2},      
    {name: "Степан", surname: "Степанов", test: 4}      
  };
  std::cout << "\nДо сортировки:" << std::endl;
  for(const auto &i:student) std::cout << i.surname << " " << i.name << " : " << i.test << std::endl;  
  std::sort(std::begin(student),std::end(student),[&](StudentsType &one, StudentsType &two) {
    return one.test>two.test;    
  });    
  std::cout << "\nПосле сортировки:" << std::endl;
  for(const auto &i:student) std::cout << i.surname << " " << i.name << " : " << i.test << std::endl;    
  return 0;        
}
```

Вывод:

```
До сортировки:
Иванов Иван : 3
Петров Петр : 2
Степанов Степан : 4

После сортировки:
Степанов Степан : 4
Иванов Иван : 3
Петров Петр : 2
```

[Тест на ideone](http://ideone.com/ftGx3o).

Answer (score 1):

Не очень все же понятно. Но - вот два варианта. Структуры сортируются по полю, во втором варианте хранятся в векторе (или массиве, не важно) как указатели.

Смотрите, уточняйте непонятное...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    int field;
    char bigData[20];
    Data(int x):field(x){};
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Первый вариант
    vector<Data> d;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) d.push_back(Data(rand()%30));
    sort(d.begin(),d.end(),
         [](const Data& d1, const Data& d2) { return d1.field < d2.field; });
    for(auto e: d)
        cout << e.field << endl;

    cout << "-----------8<-----------\n";

    // Второй вариант
    vector<Data*> p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) p.push_back(new Data(rand()%30));
    sort(p.begin(),p.end(),
         [](const Data* d1, const Data* d2) { return d1->field < d2->field; });
    for(auto e: p)
        cout << e->field << endl;


}
```

Comment: хорошо, я уточню. Допустим, надо отсортировать структуру. которую дал изначально. Вот сортиировка через указатели, но она не работает. 

Students **p;
 for (int i = 0; i < col - 1; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < col - i - 1; j++)
  {
   if (p[j]->test1 + p[j]->test2 + p[j]->test3 < p[j+1]->test1 + p[j+1]->test2 + p[j+1]->test3)
   {
    Students *temp = p[j];
    p[j] = p[j + 1];
    p[j + 1] = temp;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Если бы вы еще для начала изложили, как получаете `p`, что оно собой реально представляет...

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду, что сам исходный массив студентов не должен сортироваться, а сортируются лишь массив указателей на исходный массив, то программа, к примеру, может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    int test1;
};

struct SortStudents
{
    static bool byName(const Student *first, const Student *second)
    {
        return first->name < second->name;
    }

    static bool bySurname(const Student *first, const Student *second)
    {
        return first->surname < second->surname;
    }

    static bool byTest(const Student *first, const Student *second)
    {
        return first->test1 < second->test1;
    }
};

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os,  Student &st)
{
    return os << st.name << ' ' << st.surname << ' ' << st.test1;
}

int main()
{
    Student students[] =
    {
        { "A", "YY", 10 },
        { "C", "ZZ", 6 },
        { "B", "XX", 12 }
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof(students) / sizeof(*students);

    Student *pStudents[N];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) pStudents[i] = &students[i];

    std::cout << "Sorted by name" << std::endl;

    std::sort(std::begin(pStudents), std::end(pStudents),
        SortStudents::byName);

    for (auto p : pStudents)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\nSorted by surname" << std::endl;

    std::sort(std::begin(pStudents), std::end(pStudents),
        SortStudents::bySurname);

    for (auto p : pStudents)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\nSorted by tests" << std::endl;

    std::sort(std::begin(pStudents), std::end(pStudents),
        SortStudents::byTest);

    for (auto p : pStudents)
    {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
Sorted by name
A YY 10
B XX 12
C ZZ 6

Sorted by surname
B XX 12
A YY 10
C ZZ 6

Sorted by tests
C ZZ 6
A YY 10
B XX 12
```

Answer (score -1):

Все, у меня получилось. Ниже привожу код программы, col - количество студентов

```
Students **p;
p = new Students*[col];
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    p[i] = &student[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < col - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col - i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (p[j]->test1 + p[j]->test2 + p[j]->test3 < p[j+1]->test1 + p[j+1]->test2 + p[j+1]->test3)
        {
            Students *temp = p[j];
            p[j] = p[j + 1];
            p[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы используете метку `с++` - не стесняйтесь пользоваться с++))